# Duplicate a post programmatically

Tags: wordpress, post, duplicates

Going to explain this as best as possible. I'm working on a project, where we are building a WordPress based app. We have a user interface that includes a button to duplicate a post. However, this part always fails because of the nonce.

I have been able to create a nonce, but the nonce does not pass verification. I believe because I'm calling to duplicate the post from a page other than the admin.php page.

My question - is it possible to duplicate a post from another page and then get directed to the new draft post? Has anyone ever accomplished this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for the same. If you wish to change the post type while duplicating the page or post you may require to change one of the arguments. Please check my code and it's comments.

You need to call this function and pass the parameter of your post id.

```
function duplicate_post($post_id) {
$title   = get_the_title($post_id);
$oldpost = get_post($post_id);
$post    = array(
  'post_title' => $title,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_type' => $oldpost->post_type,
  'post_author' => 1
);
$new_post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
// Copy post metadata
$data = get_post_custom($post_id);
foreach ( $data as $key => $values) {
  foreach ($values as $value) {
    add_post_meta( $new_post_id, $key, $value );
  }
}

return $new_post_id;
}
```

Comment: This code works to duplicate the post. I added the additional information I needed and now we have a working button to duplicate our custom post type! Thank you so much!

Comment: @kindredx  thanks for confirming. If possible please accept my answer so other can get to know that this code is working.